What is the generalized univariate change-of-variables formula?
I have a normally-distributed random variable $I$ with a few sample points and a given standard deviation $\sigma$.
I need to transform the random variable, its samples and its standard deviation through $\sin(I)$. Following 3.7 Transformations of Random Variables,

but of course $\sin$ is non-monotonic. The text then skips to a generalised multivariate form that should not be necessary because $I$ is univariate.
What is the generalised form of the change-of-variables formula that does not have a monotonic requirement but is still univariate, and how does this apply to $\sin$ ?

The reason there is no general formula is that the result depends on how the transformation fails to be monotonic; and transformations can differ from being monotonic in myriad complicated ways.  The duplicate uses your example of a sine transformation to illustrate the general result and ends up with a fully general formula for that specific function.
